# Neutral command to hide footnotes from wordcount

Tags: footnotes, acronyms

I currently have do all of my citations and footnotes with the commands `\ac` and `\fn` respectively, which I have set up as shorter versions of the full commands. I want to be able to print my document without any footnotes or citations, so I figure the best way would be to redefine temporarily these short commands. Basically, I need a command that will not print the text and will allow anything to be entered as options, i.e. a kind of dummy command.

Comment: What is the default usage of `\fn` or `\ac`? Do you have any optional arguments? Please provide a minimal working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\newif\ifprint
\def\fn#1{\ifprint \footnote{#1} \else \fi}
```

And if you do not want printing footnotes etc., write

```
\printfalse
```